# why does `udev` consume full memory in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, shell, udev

Here is the result of `df -h` on my system.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1,9G  1,9G     0 100% /dev
tmpfs           388M   12M  377M   3% /run
/dev/sda1        92G   31G   56G  36% /
tmpfs           1,9G   66M  1,9G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3       156G   79G   70G  54% /home
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           388M   40K  388M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           388M   20K  388M   1% /run/user/120
```

I'm concerned about the memory usage by `udev`. As you can see, its size is `1.9G`. But it eats all of the available memory which is making my system *very slower* to operate. However, when I reboot the system, `used` memory is zero but it gradually takes all memory within few minutes.

Now, I'd like to understand what is causing this problem and also some explanation about `udev` memory requirement/usage. Also, please suggest how to solve this problem and make my system operate faster. I have 4GB RAM in my machine.

Comment: I don't have much faith in the numbers reported by devtmpfs.  On one of my systems, df reports 0 of 7.8G, and on another, it says 0 of 10M.  But that said, yours looks odd with 100% used.  Just be aware that it might just be a cosmetic issue, and not your problem at all.  (I assume you've used `top` and sorted by size to check processes, too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you have a script or program that keeps blindly writing to some device, but that device *doesn't exist* – so the program ends up creating a regular file and writing to it until the filesystem fills up. (It could be something as simple as mistyping `> /dev/nul` for `> /dev/null`.)

To figure out what, look for massive files under `/dev`, e.g. using *ncdu* – then search the system for any script or configuration that mentions those files.

Note that "udev" here is just shown as arbitrary "source" name for a `tmpfs` filesystem (as udev used to manage the device nodes), and has little to do with the memory usage of udev *processes*.

Comment: Thank you! *ncdu* shows that in `/dev` the `/.bootchart` consumes 1.9G of memory. Is this normal?

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit too large for bootchart – and you're probably not even using the bootchart software anyway. (Some early-boot software use `/dev` as a convenient place to stash data before any other filesystems have been mounted...)

Comment: Now, could you please tell me what should I do? So, this is not causing the problem of making my system slower?

Comment: Uninstall the bootchart software?

Comment: won't that cause any problem with normal booting? I don't have a backup system to work on :(

Comment: @kmario23: bootchart is only used to visualize the boot process. You can boot just fine without it. (I don't have it installed, for example). Details: http://www.bootchart.org/